# MySQL only show age if TIMESTAMPDIFF result below 18

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've calculated the age from birth of date and now I have to filter those results to being under 18 only. If I use <18 at the end of TIMESTAMPDIFF, I'll get 1 and 0 results only, instead of their age.

TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR,
`student_athletes`.`date_of_birth`,
CURDATE()) <18 AS Age,

thank you for the help.

Comment: Remove the `<18` from your select but keep it in your where clause. `select TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, student_athletes.date_of_birth, CURDATE()) as i_age from my_table where TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, student_athletes.date_of_birth, CURDATE()) <18`

Comment: Since you had <18 as part of the select statement, you are making it a boolean statement, such as this: `select 1=1, 1=0, 7<8` produces an output of 1, 0, 1